# How to add custom template to Generic list component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this application where several lists on diferent components are being made.
The pattern for the component is always the same.

Master list items with ADD button and a REMOVE button for each item.
But the item itself vary alot, and some have its own list items.

I was trying to create a shareable component (cause DRY huh? :D )

But I cant' get to my **ngFor** to repeat the items inside the component.

I made this
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kfqdvn?file=src/app/components/chained-item-list/chained-item-list.component.html)
with the work.

Here's my code:

**Component being used:**

```
<chained-item-list [items]="items" (onRemoveItem)="onRemoveItem($event)">
  <div class="card">
    <h4>Header Item</h4>
    <small>22/03/2022</small>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet.</p>
  </div>
</chained-item-list>
```

**Component .HTML file**

```
<div class="list-header">
  <h3>CHAINED LIST</h3>

  <button (click)="addNewItem()" title="Add Item" type="button" class="btn-add">
    Add New
  </button>
</div>
<br />

<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let indexItem = index">
    <li>
      <ng-content></ng-content>

      <button
        (click)="removeItem(indexItem)"
        title="Remove"
        type="button"
        class="btn-remove"
      >
        X
      </button>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

**Component .TS file**

```
export class ChainedItemListComponent {
  @Input() items: any[];
  @Output() onRemoveItem: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


  constructor() {}

  addNewItem() {
    this.items.push(Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)));
  }

  removeItem(indexItem: number) {
    try {
      this.onRemoveItem.emit(this.items.splice(indexItem, 1)[0]);
    } catch (e) {
      this.onRemoveItem.emit(e);
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. You need to update you component.

Change the way of passing a template, use `ng-template`.

```html
<chained-item-list [items]="items" (onRemoveItem)="onRemoveItem($event)">
  <!-- pass template using ng-template tag -->
  <ng-template>
    <div class="card">
      <h4>Header Item</h4>
      <small>22/03/2022</small>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</chained-item-list>
```

Add this line to your component ts file.

```js
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) customTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Now pass this `customTemplateRef` to the `ng-content` tag.

```html
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let indexItem = index">
    <li>
      <!-- update this line -->
      <ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="customTemplateRef"></ng-content>

      <button
        (click)="removeItem(indexItem)"
        title="Remove"
        type="button"
        class="btn-remove"
      >
        X
      </button>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

You're done. Enjoy!

Comment: Is there any way to pass "item" attributes into the component? 
Like item.header | item.date | item.text? 
Right now the template is repeated, but no information is inputed on the component

Comment: I've updated a sample code [here](https://github.com/jitesh-geitpl/ng-code-samples). Clone it and run the reusable-ng-content project by using `ng serve --project=reusable-ng-content`.  In short.  `<ng-template let-item="item"></ng-template>` and `<ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="customTemplateRef; context: { item: item }"></ng-content>`

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with defining template.

```
<chained-item-list [items]="items" (onRemoveItem)="onRemoveItem($event)">
  <ng-template #contentAccessTpl="">
    <div class="card">
      <h4>Header Item</h4>
      <small>22/03/2022</small>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</chained-item-list>
```

For safer side add condition. by assigning the Id it will make it easy to use multiple templates.

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let indexItem = index">
    <li>
      <ng-container *ngIf="contentAccessTpl">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentAccessTpl"> </ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <button
        (click)="removeItem(indexItem)"
        title="Remove"
        type="button"
        class="btn-remove"
      >
        X
      </button>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Here's forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ueyn8a).

Comment: Is there any way to pass "item" attributes into the component? 
Like item.header | item.date | item.text? 
Right now the template is repeated, but no information is inputed on the component