# Query items inside <ng-content> with ContentChild

Tags: angular

I am trying to make a custom dropdown, and face the following problem :

I have 3 directives :

- `dropdown`: which is to set on the dropdown element
- `menu`:  which is to set inside the dropdown, and over the item that is part of the
  the menu that will appear
- `item`: which is to set inside all items within a menu.

Inside the menu, I query for all items using

```
  @ContentChildren(ItemDirective) menuItems: QueryList<ItemDirective>;
```

And inside the dropdown I check all the items within the menu using

```
  @ContentChild(MenuDirective) private menu: MenuDirective;

  onKeyDown(key: string) {
    console.log(this.menu.menuItems.length);
  }
```

When it's linear like this :

```
    <button appDropdown>
      <div appMenu>
        <div *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" appItem>{{ i }}</div>
      </div>
    </button>
```

It works, but there is a case where (in a select) I want the items to be added as `ng-content` so

```
<button appDropdown>
  <div appMenu>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</button>
```

In this second case, the items are not found.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y3wtvr) (click on button then press any key and watch logs)

Is there a way to make this work ?

Comment: if you add this code it works 

<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
  <span style="margin-top:12px;">
    This one works cause no ng content involved
    <button appDropdown>
      <div appMenu>
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="simpleLink"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>

<ng-template #simpleLink>
  <div *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3]" appItem>{{ i }}</div>
</ng-template>

Comment: and this code works too 

  <span appDropdown>
    This one don't work cause ng content involved
    <app-select appMenu>
      <div *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3, 4]" appItem>{{ i }}</div>
    </app-select>
  </span>

Comment: is there a specific scenario that does not work ?

Comment: Sorry but your first snipped don't seems to work : https://imgur.com/a/Xqe5BIM

Comment: @Hanna In the main stackblitz I posted, there is 2, option, the logs should show the amount of item inside the dropdown https://imgur.com/a/L7xkPp0

Comment: My point is, I need to make a dropdown selector, so the items are dynamics, and I want to pass them via ng-content and query them inside my selector component. not do all inline.

Comment: it did work when i tried it in your stackblit, and even the select one did work

Comment: the second snipped works you have to remove appDropDown and appMenu from app-select and add them like this 
  <span appDropdown>
    This one don't work cause ng content involved
    <app-select appMenu>
      <div *ngFor="let i of [1, 2]" appItem>{{ i }}</div>
    </app-select>
  </span>

Comment: care to fork a stackblitz as solution ? @Hanna So I can see there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ContentChildren is only scoped to the components direct `<ng-content></ngcontent>` tag, and will not look up the layout tree to see if the specified content children also live in a parents `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag.

Meaning, the @ContentChildren tag will only capture content children within its directly scoped `<ng-content></ng-content`, and not from a parents `<ng-content></ng-content`.

Directly from Angulars docs: [Full Description on Angular Website.](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren#description)

> @ContentChildren does not retrieve elements or directives that are in other components' templates, since a component's template is always a black box to its ancestors.

That's why this ***does*** work ✅

```html
<button appDropdown>
  <div appMenu>
    <!-- not a black box to your appMenu directive -->
    <!-- therefore, it will be seen by your @ContentChildren tag -->
    <div *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" appItem>{{ i }}</div>
  </div>
</button>
```

That's why this ***doesn't*** work ❌

```html
<button appDropdown>
  <div appMenu>
    <!-- this is a black box to your appMenu directive -->
    <!-- because the ng-content tag is scoped to the component -->
    <!-- therefore, it WON'T be seen by your @ContentChildren tag -->
    <!-- inside the appMenu directive -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</button>
```

---

### Solution

This means you can't structure your code the way you want to with the directives that you've created, but will instead have todo something like this if you want your select component to work with ng-content.

select.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css'],
})
export class SelectComponent {

  @ContentChildren(ItemDirective) menuItems: QueryList<ItemDirective>;

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) keyDownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log('k');
    this.onKeyDown(event.code);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  constructor() {}

  onKeyDown(key: string) {
    console.log(this.menuItems.length);
  }
}
```

select.component.html

```html
<button>
  <div>
    <!-- ng-content scoped to select.component.ts -->
    <!-- therefore, your ItemDirective's will be captured by -->
    <!-- @ContentChildren if they are direct descendants inside ng-content -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: I am using querySelector to query inside the ng content. It's a nice workaround currently, but yeah maybe changing the whole structure is more solid. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71631374/10428247)?
Find out the sample code [here](https://github.com/jitesh-geitpl/ng-code-samples). Clone it and run the `reusable-ng-content` project by using `ng serve --project=reusable-ng-content`. Hope it may helpful.

Comment: hi, not really, cause this would get me a ref of the template, but not all of child items